ignore ipdb warning, running stale stale code until the program is rerun
Suddenly I am seeing warnings from the IPython debugger ipdb that my code is stale, however editing / saving code while debugging is a common use case so this warning is not helpful.
*** WARNING: file <path-to-file.py> was edited, running stale code until the program is rerun

The message appears when I use the following in <path-to-file.py> as a debug breakpoint.
from ipdb import set_trace
...
set_trace()

IPython will stop at the debug breakpoint, then after editing / saving <path-to-file.py> the warning message begins to appear in the debugger console.  Looking to completely disable this warning.
ipdb 0.13.13 ipython 8.28.0
